# What will be the complexity of this Quick Sort algorithm implemented in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I implemented a quick sort algorithm, I want to know that is this the correct way to do it, is time complexity O(nlog(n)) as seen in text books

Here is the code:

```
def quicksortA(list1):

    if len(list1) < 2:
        return list1
    else:
        pivot = list1[0]
        less = []
        more = []
        for i in list1[1:]:
            if i <= pivot:
               less.append(i)
            if i > pivot:
               more.append(i)

        return quicksortA(less) + [pivot] + quicksortA(more)
```

Comment: Did you test it? `quicksort` raises a `NameError` because your function is actually named `quicksortA`. If you fix that, then it raises an `IndexError` due to accessing `list1[0]` when `list1` is empty in a recursive call.

Comment: And when you fix these bugs, it looks like `quicksort([1, 1, 1])` gives an interesting result, and sorting an already-sorted list will not be O(N log N)! Finally, sorting random lists may average O(N log N), but the creation of multiple lists each recursion will destroy performance!

Comment: sorry guys I just edited it because of another quick sort function, now I have corrected it

Comment: @KenY-N fixed these bugs :) , now tell me about this algorithm's weakness

Comment: It would be more appropriate for [codereview.se], I think, but since your pivot is the first element, `less` will be empty and `more` will be full, so the performance will be O(N^2) or so. (I did actually encounter this case in my current project!) Next, there is a lot of list creation and deletion; I count 5 new lists each time round, which will be slow and may cause stack overflow issues. If you wish to continue reviewing, please post to [codereview.se], checking [existing questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+quicksort), thanks.

Comment: thanks man, I just implemented this myself, I knew that it's complexity will be bad. Currently I'm working on the pointer version of this algo